# useEffect - calling a function inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

How can i call a function inside setInterval of useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = setInterval(() => {getTime}, 1000); // this is Line 8
        return function cleanup() {
          clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
      }, [getTime]);

const getTime=() =>{
            console.log("Inside getTime");}
```

I want my getTime function to be invoked every 1s. I'm getting below error

```
 Line 8:46:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions.
```

Another question,I want to update state every 1sec,  can i update state inside setInterval

Comment: try `this.getTime`

Comment: It is not a class, functional component

Comment: Try getTime() in existing  or setInterval(getTime,1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
() => {getTime}
```

references the `getTime` function but doesn't do anything with it. You're not calling the function. That's what the linter is warning you about.

Why not pass the `getTime` function alone into `setInterval`, without an unnecessary anonymous wrapper?

```
const timeoutId = setInterval(getTime, 1000);
```

Also note that since you're setting an *interval*, not a timeout, you should use `clearInterval`, not `clearTimeout`.

> can i update state inside setInterval

Sure, but keep in mind that if you have other state variables you want to reference in the process, they may not be up-to-date in the interval's closure. If that's an issue, either use refs as well, or clear and restart the timeout whenever a state variable changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do if `getTime()` is the only function for the setInterval

```
        const timeoutId = setInterval(getTime, 1000);
```

or as follows if you have other commands in addition to `getTime()` to do inside the setInterval function.

```
        const timeoutId = setInterval(() => {getTime()}, 1000);
```